# Cytoscape does not launch correctly

Tags: java, java-11, launch

I would appreciate suggestions on what to check. I use Linux version 3.9.1 under Oracle Linux 8.

Cytoscape was launched with the following command:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink $(readlink $(which java)))))
export DISPLAY=:99
cd ~/cytoscape; ./cytoscape.sh server&
```

The java process is running, but CyRest is not launched. The error message from the terminal is the following.

Thanks!

```
(base) [test@docker cytoscape]$source t.sh
karaf.base: /home/test/cytoscape/framework
JAVA_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.22.0.7-2.0.1.el8.x86_64
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to cache bundle: mvn:org.cytoscape.distribution/third-party/3.9.1
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:3013)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.region.BundleIdBasedRegion.installBundle0(BundleIdBasedRegion.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.region.BundleIdBasedRegion.installBundleAtLocation(BundleIdBasedRegion.java:97)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.BundleInstallSupportImpl.installBundle(BundleInstallSupportImpl.java:135)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.installBundle(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1138)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:900)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1062)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.lambda$doProvisionInThread$13(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:998)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: Invalid CEN header (invalid extra data field size for tag: 0xbfef at 1309602)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1769)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.checkExtraFields(ZipFile.java:1274)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1734)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1463)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1426)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:742)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:859)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:257)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:186)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:200)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.openZipFile(SecureAction.java:650)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.WeakZipFileFactory$WeakZipFile.<init>(WeakZipFileFactory.java:187)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.WeakZipFileFactory$WeakZipFile.<init>(WeakZipFileFactory.java:169)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.WeakZipFileFactory.create(WeakZipFileFactory.java:72)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarRevision.<init>(JarRevision.java:84)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleArchive.createRevisionFromLocation(BundleArchive.java:872)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleArchive.reviseInternal(BundleArchive.java:550)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleArchive.<init>(BundleArchive.java:153)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.create(BundleCache.java:277)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:3009)
        ... 12 more
```